# NameError: name 'mocker' is not defined using pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-mock

I'm learning to use mock when testing with pytest.

I got a simple test function:

```
import pytest
import smtplib

def test_send_email():
    with mocker.patch('smtplib.SMTP') as mock:
        assert True
```

But when I try to run this test I got the following error: `NameError: name 'mocker' is not defined`.

I already verified that `mock`, `pytest` and `pytest-mock` are correctly installed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Welll. was a stupide error... I was missing the `mocker` parameter...

It should be:

```
def test_send_email(mocker):
    with mocker.patch('smtplib.SMTP') as mock:
        assert True
```

Comment: I couldn't figure this out either lol - seems I missed the fact that they were passing a param in the doc examples